# How do I remove a specific number of files using python (version 2.5)?

Tags: python, file

I would like to remove two files from a folder at the conclusion of my script. Do I need to create a function responsible for removing these two specific files? I would like to know in some detail how to use os.remove (if that is what I should use) properly. These two files will always be discarded at the conclusion of my script (which packages a series of files together in a zip format). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just call `os.remove("path/to/file")`. For example, to remove the file `.emacs`, call

```
os.remove(".emacs")
```

The path should be a `str` that's the pathname of the file. It may be relative or absolute.

Comment: os.remove(os.path.expanduser("~/.emacs"))

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like what you really want is a temp file:
http://docs.python.org/library/tempfile.html

Answer (score 0):

It is perfectly acceptable to have a 'cleanup()' function that you call at the end of your script, which will call 'os.remove()' on your files.